# Arquillian Test java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: I - how to use Randombeans

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I want to use [Randombeans](https://github.com/benas/random-beans) in my Arquillian JPA tests. The problem is i get this Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: I
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at io.github.benas.randombeans.ObjectFactory.createNewInstance(ObjectFactory.java:68)
    at io.github.benas.randombeans.ObjectFactory.createInstance(ObjectFactory.java:60)
    at io.github.benas.randombeans.EnhancedRandomImpl.doPopulateBean(EnhancedRandomImpl.java:113)
...
```

(there is no cause)

Before this i got exceptions for classes in random beans and Objenesis i added the complete packages to my arquillian deployment.
Adding `sun.reflect` package does not help.

But how to add class "I" or how to get Arquillian tests running that uses random beans?

Comment: Hi, random beans author here. I would love to help. Strange stack trace indeed.. Can you share your code somewhere so I can run it and inspect your classpath?

Comment: meanwhile i reverted the code. an it is far away to be a minimum example. but i guess this is reproducible withe every arquillian test: "just" create an jpa entity class and write an arquillian test that persists a random bean of that class. - at the moment i do not have time to create such an example.